Showing that $L^\infty(X,\mu)$ is 1-injective for any locally compact non-empty $X$.
Let $E$ be a Banach space and let $G$ be another Banach space, denote by $B(E,G)$ the space of bounded linear operators $T:E\to G$. We will call $E$ injective if for every Banach space $G$, each closed subset $F$ of $G$ and each $T\in B(F,E)$, the exists an extension $\tilde{T}\in B(G,E)$. A Banach space is called $p$-injective if in addition we can find such a $\tilde{T}$ such that $\|\tilde{T}\|\leq p\|T\|$.
Consider a non-empty locally compact space $X$ and let $\mu$ be a measure on $X$. I wish to show that $L^\infty(X,\mu)$ is a 1-injective space.
My attempt is as follows: We know that $L^\infty(X,\mu)$ is isometrically isomoprhic to its Gel'fand transform $C(\Phi)$ (i.e., the character space of $L^\infty(X,\mu)$) and moreover $\Phi$ is a Stonean space. Now each Stonean space is projective, that is to say for any compact spaces $N$,$M$ and continuous surjections $\theta:M\to N$ and $\varphi:\Phi\to N$, there is a continuous map $\psi:\Phi\to M$ such that $\varphi=\theta\circ\psi$. But this implies that $\Phi$ is a retract of $\beta\Phi'$, the Stone-Cech compactification of $\Phi'$, where $\Phi'$ is $\Phi$ endowed with the discrete topology. Said another way, there is a retraction $\theta:\beta\Phi'\to \Phi$.
Consequently, if $\vartheta:\Phi\to\beta\Phi'$ is the natural embedding, then $\theta\circ\vartheta$ is the identity on $\Phi$. It follows that $\theta':C(\Phi)\to C(\beta\Phi')$ is an isometry and $\vartheta':C(\beta\Phi')\to\theta'(C(\Phi))$ is linear, and moreover a surjection with $\|\vartheta'\|=1$.
Yet, this is where I get stuck. My intuition says that we can use the fact that $\vartheta'\circ\theta'$ is the identity on $C(\Phi)$, the conclusion follows, yet I cant seem to see the last steps.
Any ideas are welcome!
————————————————————————
Update: I believe to have found the answer using a result in Phillips, which I posted below as an answer.

By Corollary 7.2 in Phillips, for any non-empty $X$, $\ell^\infty(X)= C(\beta X)$ is 1-injective and as $\theta'$ is an isometry, it follows that $C(\Phi)$ is 1-injective. Indeed, $\vartheta'\circ\theta'$ is the identity on $C(\Phi)$, and so $\vartheta'$ is a bounded projection, and as $C(\Phi)$ is isometrically isomorphic to $L^\infty(X,\mu)$, this implies that $L^\infty(X,\mu)$ is 1-injective.
